# How to str_replace \ symbol in php

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a string containing '\' in it but when i replaced the string with blank
it showing error.

```
$emailbody = str_replace('\','',$emailbody);
```

Thank you all

Comment: what is your email body can you please put it here and what exactly you want?

Comment: Please provide some more context, providing a [minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `stripslashes` for this

```
 $emailbody = "hello \ its a testing\ string";
 echo $emailbody = stripslashes($emailbody);
```

**Note** that `stripslashes` only remove `backslashes` not forward

Or

```
echo $emailbody =  str_replace("\\","",$emailbody);
```

Output

```
hello its a testing string
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$emailbody = str_replace('\\', '', $emailbody);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape your backslash so... `\\`

Answer (score 0):

try this,
use `\/`

```
$emailbody = str_replace('\/','',$emailbody);
```